# How to "translate" <script>-s to webpack bundle?

Tags: webpack

I have a project that js files are imported using script tags.

```
 <script src="js\first.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js\second.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**first.js:**

```
console.log('*******************************first');

function hello() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

**second.js**

```
console.log('************************second');
hello();
```

As you can see, file second.js calls a function that lies in first.js file.

I understood that if we want to do it in Webpack, I'll have to use an 'import' statement in 'first.js' that points to the file 'second.js'.

The problem is that my project is combined of many js files and I really don't want to get deep inside and write 'import' for every js file. I just want to replace the multiple script tags in one script tag pointing to a bundle js.

Comment: If you just want to concatenate a bunch of script files together but don't want or need to define dependencies between them, then webpack is probably not the right tool for the job. There are simpler tools for concatenating scripts ... Webpack is probably not worth the effort unless you're ready to "modularize" your code.